# nuxt get username after hit this.$auth.fetchUser()

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

hello i am trying to get username after fetchUser methods but its getting undefine

I am trying like this

```
   async loginUser() {
      this.$auth.setUserToken(`${this.token}`);
      this.$auth.setStrategy('local');
      await this.$auth
        .fetchUser()
        .then(() => {
          console.log(this.$auth.user); //<- this getting false i want user details
        })
        .catch(e => {
          // console.log(e)
          this.$auth.logout();
          return this.$router.push(
            `/${
              this.$route.query.origin ? this.$route.query.origin : 'register'
            }?error=1`,
          );
        });
    },
```

my States after Commit `Auth\SET` 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it using this logic

```
async loginUser() {
      this.$auth.setUserToken(`${this.token}`);
      this.$auth.setStrategy('local');
      await this.$auth
        .fetchUser()
        .then(() => {
//Added This for get user details then redirect to username page
          this.$axios.get('/me').then(response => {
            return this.$router.push(`/${response.data.data.username}`);
          });
        })
        .catch(e => {
          // console.log(e)
          this.$auth.logout();
          return this.$router.push(
            `/${
              this.$route.query.origin ? this.$route.query.origin : 'register'
            }?error=1`,
          );
        });
    },
```